# Convert comma seperated string to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string `[[358, 239]]`.

How to add values to `ArrayList<String>` such that it takes value `358` at index=`0` and value `239` at index=`1` and so on.

p.s.: i saw many solutions but none of them work for me.

Comment: do you have an array inside array?

Comment: That looks like an array of array of integers. You can use a library like jackson to do json de-serialization and get the array list you want.

Comment: If you have a question about non-working code then post the code as a [mcve] and describe what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trim the two `[[` at the start and `]]` at the end first  and then `split` the `String`.

Sample code :

```
String s = "[[358, 239]]";
s = s.substring(2, s.length() - 2); // becomes 358, 239

List<String> result = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));    
System.out.println(result);
```

Outputs :

```
[358,  239]
```